# How do I count how many digits are in every string of an array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

The instructions are to count how many digits are in every string of an array and assign to numberDigits.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
public void computeStatistics(String []strings){    
    numberDigits = 0;
    for(String s : strings){
        for(int i : s.toCharArray()){
            if(i >= 0 || i <= 2)
                numberDigits++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not `numberDigits += s.length ();`  BUT is there supposed to be a separate numberDigits  for each String?

Comment: `if(i >= 0 || i <= 2)` will always return true, what are you trying to test?

Comment: Do you mean number of characters of the string that are digits? Or the length of the string?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if i understood your question correctly are you counting the number of digits in a string array?
    `public int computeStatistics(String []strings){
      int numberDigits = 0;
      for(String s : strings){
        s = s.replaceAll("\D+","");
        numberDigits = numberDigits + s.length();
      }
      return numberDigits;
    }`

Comment: s = s.replaceAll("\\D+","");    numberDigits = numberDigits + s.length();                                                                  these statements actually fixed it. Just replaced my 2nd for loop and numberDigits++ with yours and it did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @stgray cool. not really the most optimized solution, but the shortest one to code. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your string is alpha nummeric. Your if condition is wrong. char datatype have integer representations of their corresponding ASCII value. So char a = 'A' when casted to int is actually stored as 65.  So the char '0' which is stored in the array you are iterating over is stored in i as 48. You are checking between 0 to 9 ascii codes and hence this code wont work. Either change if condition to

```
if(i>=48 && i<=57)
```

Or what i find as a good general policy is to keep char as char.

```
for(char ch:s.toCharArrat())
    if(ch>='0' && ch<='9')
```

This way you wont have to think about ascii. For converting char '0' to int do the following.

```
int i = (int)ch - (int)'0';
```

This will give corresponding integers.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, since overall digits count matter, all strings can be concatenated to single and each character can be checked for if it is digit.

```
public  void computeStatistics(String[] strings) {

    numberDigits = 0;
    //Converting all strings in array to single string 
    String cmbStr = Arrays.toString(strings);

    for (Character c : cmbStr.toCharArray()) {
        //checking each character is digit
        if (Character.isDigit(c))
            numberDigits++;
    }
}
```